# Chain Rule, Piecewise Derivative

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have a function $h(a,b)=g(f(a,b))$ where $f(a,b)$ is a smooth, continuous, multivariate function and $g(x)$ is a piecewise function s.t. $$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1, & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
      x, & x > 1
   \end{cases}
$$
How would I go about solving $\frac{\partial h(a,b)}{\partial a}$?

Edit: I also want to say that though $f(a,b)$ only depends upon two variables, the number of variables are not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The partial derivative will be piecewise as well:

$\frac{\partial h(a,b)}{\partial a}= g'(f(a,b))\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=
0$, by the chain rule.

If $f(a,b)$ is between 0 and 1, since $g$ is constant, and if $f(a,b)>1$, 
$g'=1$ and $g'(f(a,b))\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}=\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a}$

This will be true for any smooth scalar valued function $f$ mapping into the domain of $g$.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks for the help! I guess that bounding does matter at least in this case since $g(1)$ can be flipped into either domain.

Comment: nothing in the above reasoning uses that $f$ is mapping from $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The same reasoning would apply for $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. I am not sure I understand what you mean by $g(1)$ being flipped in either domain.

Comment: I should have said interval instead of domain. Sorry. What I meant was that since $g(x)$ is continuous while $g'(x)$ has a break at $g'(1)$, how I define the intervals of $g(x)$ does matter.

Comment: But the intervals of $g(x)$ (i think you mean piecewise definition of $g(x)$) is separate from how many variables the inside function $f$ takes as arguments.

Comment: Oh, that edit was before you even answered. I guess what I'm asking is that say $f(a^{*},b^{*})=1$, then $\frac{\partial h(a,b)}{\partial a} \mid_{a=a^{*},b=b^{*}}$ at could equal $0$ or $\frac{\partial f(a,b)}{\partial a} \mid_{a=a^{*},b=b^{*}}$ depending upon how I define the intervals of $g(x)$?

Comment: ah yes now i understand. No, so this is why it is important that one the inequalities of your definition of $g$ be strict. There is no ambiguity in the way you define your (piecewise) continuous derivative. At 1, $g(x=1)=1$ and therefore $g'(1)=0$. If both inequalities were not strict, the function would be well defined there, but the derivative would not be.